# Copy and overwrite a file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, copy

I want to copy a certain file to a location, irrespective of that file already exists in the destination or not. I'm trying to copy through shell script.But the file is not getting copied. I'm using the following command

`/bin/cp -rf /source/file /destination`

but that doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you should try --remove-destination

Comment: `cp` overrides the destination unless option `-n` is given, so your command should succeed. Also you didn't tell us why you think your command fails.

Comment: Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This question has been already discussed, however you can write a little script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -d "$2" ]; then
  mkdir -p "$2"
fi
cp -R "$1" "$2"
```

### Explaining this script a little bit

1. `#!/bin/bash`: tells your computer to [use the `bash` interpreter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter).
2. `if [ ! -d "$2" ]; then`: If the second variable you supplied does not already exist...
3. `mkdir -p "$2"`: make that directory, including any parent directories supplied in the path.

   Running `mkdir -p one/two/three` will make:

   ```
   $ mkdir -p one/two/three
   $ tree one
   one/
   └── two
       └── three
   ```

   If you don't supply the `-p` tag then you'll get an error if directories `one` and `two` don't exist:

   ```
   $ mkdir one/two/three
   mkdir: cannot create directory ‘one/two/three’: No such file or directory
   ```
4. `fi`: Closes the *if* statement.
5. `cp -R "$1" "$2"`: copies files from the first variable you supplied to the directory of the second variable you supplied.

   So if you ran `script.sh mars pluto`, `mars` would be the first variable (`$1`) and `pluto` would be the second variable (`$2`).

   The `-R` flag means it does this recursively, so the `cp` command will go through **all** the files and folders from your first variable, and copy them to the directory of your second variable.

Answer (score 26):

Use

```
cp -fr /source/file /destination
```

this should probably solve the problem.

Answer (score 15):

Your problem might be caused by an alias for cp command created in your system by default (you can see al your aliases by typing "alias").
For example, my system has the following alis by default: alias cp='cp -i', where -i overrides -f option, i.e. cp will always prompt for overwriting confirmation.

What you need in such case (that'll actually work even if you don't have an alias) is to feed "yes" to that confirmation. To do that simply modify your cp command to look like this:

yes | cp /source/file /destination

Answer (score 1):

/bin/cp -rf src dst
or
/usr/bin/env cp -rf

Comment: this is because OP could unknowingly have cp aliased to 'cp -i', and I think some (all?) systems will prioritize the -i option. For example, on my system:
`> which cp
alias cp='cp -i'
 /bin/cp

> cp abc.txt efg.txt
cp: overwrite `efg.txt'? n

> cp -f abc.txt efg.txt
cp: overwrite `efg.txt'? n`