# Linux command that Create and Copy Files and Folder in Multiple directories

Tags: linux

I have websites folders in my **/home directory** of **centos 7**. i want to copy robot.txt and favicon.ico file in all websites directories.

Websites directory structure are as following:

```
/home/domain.com/public_html
/home/domain2.com/public_html
```

I want command which copy robot.txt and favicon in all websites public_html directory from `/root/robots.txt` and `/root/favicon.ico` and if file already available on the destination folder then the command will overwrite file.

Many Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy and overwrite a file in shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855904/copy-and-overwrite-a-file-in-shell-script)

Comment: @hotzst It's not like that question. This question is about how to loop over different source directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` too.

```
find /home -type d -name public_html -exec cp /root/robots.txt /root/favicon.ico {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple `for` loop that processes each directory.

```
for dest in /home/domain*.com/public_html
do
    cp /root/robots.txt /root/favicon.ico $dest
done
```